# GetFtpConnection - upload files

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ftp

I'm not able to upload files onto an ftp site. My code to upload looks like below

```
pConn = session.GetFtpConnection(_T("<servername>"),_T("<uname>"),_T("    <password>"),INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER,TRUE);
        sTemp = sFileName.Right(sFileName.GetLength() - sFileName.ReverseFind('\\') - 1);
    bRet = pConn->PutFile(sFileName,/*_T("first.bmp") +*/ sTemp);
```

i need to upload files on folder

```
  ftp://<myservername>/Myfolder/
```

Regards,
Mohan

Comment: Please post more code on how you create the connection and the methods you use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code did the trick

```
if( !pConn->SetCurrentDirectory("/foldr/Myfolder"))MessageBox("Error: ");
```